# Hyperlinking square brackets bug?

Tags: bug, markdown

Adding a link automatically escape square brackets:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on [] = `[\[\]][1]`

But what about when linking a code sample containing brackets:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on `[]` = [`\[\]`](https://google.com)

Shouldn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> **not escape** brackets when they are contained in a code sample? like this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on `[]` = [`[]`](https://google.com)

Comment: When I `Control-L` on `[]` in a code block I get `[\[\]][1]`