# Making backticked code, with square brackets a link, introduces redundant slashes

Tags: bug, markdown

If I take some text 'hello world['malbolge']' and wrap it in backticks, all is fine:

`hello_world['malbolge']`

but if I then select it and make it a link (via the editor buttons, or <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd>), you get some superfluous escape slashes:

[`hello_world\['malbolge'\]`](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Text#Malbolge)

The editor adds `\` to escape the a;ready escaped `[]`. The link works fine without them: [`hello_world['malbolge']`](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Text#Malbolge)

Comment: Pretty sure I saw this before... Not particularly easy to search for it, though.

Comment: Isn't it the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340178/hyperlinking-square-brackets-bug)?

Comment: @yivi I just found two, and I've voted to close mine.